# Compact Framework 3.5 - DataSet Run-Time Connection String

Tags: compact-framework, xsd, dataset, connection-string, strongly-typed-dataset

I found an [MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228730%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that says I can use the ConnectionString property of the .XSD file to change the DataSet's ConnectionString at run-time.

This sets an element in the .csproj file called "RuntimeConnectionString".

However, it doesn't change the tableadapters' ConnectionString when I deploy it to my Motorola MC9190-G device (Windows Mobile 6.5.1).

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?  What are the appropriate/alternate options to change the connection string for run-time with Compact Framework?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: At this point I have to ask "why are you using a DataSet in the first place?"  DataSets are painfully slow and unbelievable memory hogs.  In a CF app they are usually a death knell.  As a data point, I've been writing managed apps for devices since about 2002 (since before the CF was even called the CF) and I have *never* used a DataSet beyond testing that showed it as a pig.  Ever.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a whole day in searching for solution to this problem.
Looks like it is a Visual Studio bug (I use VS2008Professional and had being stuck on this too).
Two possible actions in this case are:
1) Change the tableAdapter (TA) connectionString manually just before the TA had being constructed (before connection to db being opened in fact).

```
// something like this:
if (storageDataSetUtil.DesignerUtil.IsRunTime())
{
    // path to database file in my mobile device
    this.employeesTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = @"/Program Files/MyApp/data/storage.s3db";

    // VS2008-generated code for auto-filling table at runtime:
    this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.storageDataSet.employees);
}
```

2) Use statement '|DataDirectory|' (without quotes) in connectionString for your TA. In dataSet designer (schema) select TA and show its properties. Expand 'Connection' field and choose connection that you NOT use to connect to database (VS2008 usually creates one when you binding dataSet to WinForms controls. Create new connection for TA manually, if not). Thus, connectionString for database connection remains unchanged.
Using |DataDirectory| allows you to use relative paths to your DB file and being a platform-independent in most cases. As for me, this helps. Hope, this helps you too.

P.S. Sorry for poor English)